# Why does this not cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java

```
public class Null {
    public static void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ((Null) null).greet();
    }
}
```

program output: `Hello world!`.

I thought it would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Why is it happenning?

Comment: Such eye hurting code - why o why would you do this?

Comment: `.greet()` is a `static` method, so it does not actually access the instance of a class.  It merely needs to know the type of the object (`Null`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `greet()` is a `static` method. References to static methods via variables do not result in dereferencing the pointer. The compiler should have warned you about this.

If you remove the `static` modifier then you will get the `npe`

Answer (score 12):

method `greet()` is static, thus it does not need an enclosing instance of `Null`. Actually, you can [and should] invoke it as: `Null.greet();`